# calling an http service with angular in ionic with async and await

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm designing an app with ionic framework which returns a service is called to display a list of products. When I call the API I get this error

```
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Observable<Object>>'. Did you forget to use 'await'?
```

SERVICE.ts

```
async testCall() {
  const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
    message : 'Please Wait...'
  });
  await loading.present();

  const headers = this.getHeaders();
  const foodList = await this.http.post('https://api/view', {
    paginate: 5,
    page: 1
  }, {headers});
  loading.dismiss();

  return await foodList.pipe(tap(_ => {
  })
  );
}
```

COMPONENT

```
 async ngOnInit() {
    await this.productService.testCall().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.productService.list = data.result.data;
    });
  }
```

any help on how to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead:

**service:**

```
testCall() {   
  const headers = this.getHeaders();
  const foodList = this.http.post('https://api/view', {
    paginate: 5,
    page: 1
  }, {headers});

  return foodList.pipe(tap(_ => {
  }));
}
```

**component:**

```
ngOnInit() {

  const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
    message : 'Please Wait...'
  });
  loading.present();

  this.productService.testCall().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.productService.list = data.result.data;
      loading.dismiss();
  });
}
```

> **TIP:** Notice how I moved the "loading" UI calls to the component instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const foodList = await this.http.post('https://api/view', {
    paginate: 5,
    page: 1
  }, {headers}).toPromise();
```

```
this.productService.list = await this.productService.testCall();
```